# please demystify this null

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am calling a web service in my project, for handling web service result there is a method, which tells what is returned by service. Other methods use this value for further process.

network problem, webserivce problem or any xyz reason, webserivce handling method return (null) value.

Now I have to perform nul checks, two approaches worked for me

```
if([val isEqualToString:@"(null)"]) ...

if(!val) ...
```

there are many questions regarding checking null, but not clearing my concepts.
Some says check length if I check the length like `val.length` it will be 6, because handler method return the "(null)". And `!val` I am not clear how this works. Some also says check isKindOfClass [NSNull null] ...

Please can any one demystify this null.

Please don't give comparison of nil vs Nil vs Null ...

Comment: Do you want to see if the NSString expression *evaluates to nil* or if the NSString *represents the text `"(null)"`* or if the (non-nil) NSString is *empty* (length = 0)?

Comment: How can both approaches work for you? They do different things.

Comment: i want perform null check like (val == null), but handler method is returning (null), and as i said i don't know about !val

Comment: @janusfidel: That would log as `<null>`.

Comment: two approaches are working for me if([val isEqualToString:@"(null)"]) ...

if(!val) ... i want to know the logic and reason and standard approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(!val)` will test if `val` is `null`. That should be what you want to use, plain and simple. `if(val == nil)` is equivalent.

`[val isEqualToString:@"null"]` will, as the name suggests, test if `val` is equal to the *string* "null" which would most certainly make it not `null`.

`[val isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]` has no relevance to you right now, so don't worry about it.

**Edit since you asked for an explanation of `NSNull`**:

Sometimes, you need to be able to store the *concept* of `nil` rather than `nil` itself.

Suppose you wanted an array with `nil` inside it. You want your array to look like `[obj1, obj2, nil, obj3]`.

You can't declare an array like `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:obj1, obj2, nil, obj3, nil]` because as it goes through the arguments, when it sees `nil` it'll stop. This will result in the array `[obj1, obj2]`, which is not what you wanted.

So what do you do in a situation like this? You make your array `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:obj1, obj2, [NSNull null], obj3]`. Now you have an *object* in your array, but this particular object is one that everyone in the system has agreed to call "null." **It's not actually null.**

What's really going on here is `[NSNull null]` is a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). When you call `[NSNull null]`, it returns a static instance of `NSNull`. If you call `[NSNull null]` again, it'll return that same object, regardless of where you call the method. Because there is exactly one `NSNull` instance in the whole entire world of your app, it's *equivalent* to null because there will never be an object at that same address that doesn't have a null meaning.

So, as I said above, it's not relevant to you at all. You only need `NSNull` if you need a legitimate Objective-C object but you want it to be "null." It's usually safer to use `NSNull` than simply a string `@"(null)"` or something like that because it could be possible to overwrite the value of that string, mess up the string comparison, sometime down the line you might need to store the string `@"(null)"` in the same data structure as you're storing the null object, etc.

Comment: thanks a lot for really useful reply, but i am trying to learn behaviors of null, please help me regarding this null. That why i wanna know every thing including iskindofclass:[ns=null class]

Comment: Edited my answer and explained `NSNull`. Got pretty wordy but let me know if you want anything else explained.